# Usando MySQLi, consulta com erro

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$escolha = $_POST['unidade'];

if($escolha == 'ut')
{
    $conn = new mysqli($host1, $user, $pass, $bd);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die(mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }else{
            $consulta = $conn->query("SELECT nm_usu FROM usuarios;");
            while ($resultado = $consulta->fetch()) {
                echo "Nome: {$resultado['nm_usu']}<br/>";
            }
        }
}
```

E estou com seguinte erro:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch() in

Pelo que vi não está muito diferente de exemplos que outros sites, mas o que realmente pode ser? Ou qual é a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: vc está usando PDO ou mysqli ?

Comment: Não entendi, você cita `PDO` na pergunta mas usa `MySQLi` em todo o código. A mensagem do erro me parece auto-explicativa, a variável `$consulta` é uma instância da classe [mysqli_result](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli-result.php) e a mesma não possui um método chamado `fetch`. Organize melhor sua pergunta para que possamos te ajudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta trocara linha

```
while ($resultado = $consulta->fetch()) {
```

por

```
while ($resultado = $consulta->fetch_array()) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Para utilizar uma conexão com o [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php), chame ele e não o [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

no lugar de :

```
$conn = new mysqli($host1, $user, $pass, $bd);
```

troque por:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=base', 'usuario', 'senha');
```

Comment: Entendi, mas nesse caso o mysqli estou usando pq estou dentro o zendframework e estou meio que fazendo uma 'gambiarra' mesmo. =(